# Can I display the array key and value without using foreach?

Tags: php, arrays, foreach

I don't like to use the `foreach` for every little array, I hear'd it is also possible to replace it with some `array_` function, but I forget the function name.

This is what I wan't to reach:

```
$down = array (
    "file.rar" => $l->get()->fileDesc(),
    "file1.rar" => $l->get()->clientDesc()
);
```

normally, I'm using this to display the data:

```
foreach ( $down as $key => $value )
     $data .= $key . ' = ' . $value . '<br/>';
```

So it'll return:

```
//echo $data;
    file.rar = File Description One
    file1.rar = Client Description
```

It there a way to prevent from using the `foreach` and display the same `$data` anyway?

I'm just curious, so please be nice.

Comment: Why wouldn't you use a foreach? You can struggle with [`array_keys`](http://php.net/array-keys), but a foreach is the easiest thing you can do.

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking that you haven't answered in your own post. If you simply want to see what's in an array for debug purposes use what @tandu suggested.

Comment: @rdlowrey Did I said anywhere its for debuging purposes? I didnt, because, I don't want to use `foreach` but I want to use `_some_function_` I've seen that function before, but I forgot its name, unfotunately.

Comment: @Cyclone Then I suggest [Reading The Fine Manual entry on array functions](http://us3.php.net/manual/en/ref.array.php) over at php headquarters instead of saying, "hey, how about you guys tell me so I don't have to use a search feature."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why don't you just write your own function?

```
function print_array($down) {
   $data = '';
   foreach ( $down as $key => $value )
      $data .= $key . ' = ' . $value . '<br/>';
   return $data;
}
```

Comment: I don't know why you accepted this answer... It use a foreachloop so it's exactly the same as your code...

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`print_r`](http://php.net/print-r) with true on the second parameter, but I would suggest to use a foreach (as I say in my comment)

```
<?php
  $data = print_r($down, true);
?>
```

Comment: wrap it with <pre> and </pre> to see the result in a prettier format

Answer (score 0):

well the only time you would need to use a foreach is for a dynamic array. if thats not the case, just use isset to find out what is set. you can also use count if your just trying to figure out how big an array is.